# "@angular/cli": "7.1.4" Unknown option: '--es5BrowserSupport'

Tags: angular-cli, polyfills

we need to enables conditionally loaded ES2015 polyfills ;

Angular build command

```
ng build --prod --es5BrowserSupport=true
```

Give error

```
Unknown option: '--es5BrowserSupport'
```

This condition should enables conditionally loaded ES2015 polyfills.

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 8.12.0
Angular: 7.1.4
```

I checked Github, they asked me to post this support question here

Comment: You need to put the space between the keys `--prod` `--es5BrowserSupport`.

Comment: there is space already, sorry i just updated the post

Comment: i think this option is not supported by this version, i am looking for solution

Comment: I've just built my app using angular cli 7.3.3 with these keys. It successfully created the es5.polyfills file. Try to update your components to the latset version.

Answer (score 0):

Angular cli 7.3.3 with  successfully created the es5.polyfills file